# How to read in with getchar and compare it properly?

Tags: c, string-comparison, getchar

im a beginner in c and don't understand why following part of my code doesnt work:

```
        char yn;
        printf("Play again(y/n)?\n");
        while(yn!='y' && yn!='n'){
            yn=getchar();
            printf("Input:%c\n",yn);
            if(yn!='y' && yn!='n') printf("Please put in y or n!\n");
        }
```

First it reads seamingly random digits from a buffer or something, but then even if i input y or n it stays in loop even tough it confirms yn is y or n.

Comment: Do you have code before this that reads input with `scanf()`? Anything that hasn't yet been scanned will be left in the buffer.

Comment: Also, when the user presses Return, that will be a character read by `getchar()`.

Comment: The line `while(yn!='y' && yn!='n'){` will cause [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), because you are reading from an unititialized variable in the first loop iteration. You probably want to use a `do...while` loop instead of `while`.

Comment: You should initialize `yn` before using it! (`while(yn..)`)

Comment: `char yn;` --> `int yn;`, `getchar()` wants an `int` in order to handle `EOF`

Comment: You may want to read this help page: [How to create a minimal reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Your code does not compile, as it is missing the necessary header `#include` directives and also the function `main`.

Answer (score 0):

use `do while` loop it is more convenient.

```
    char yn;

    do{

        // Your play code goes here

        printf("Play again(y/n)?\n");
        printf("Input:%c\n",yn);
        yn=getchar();

        while(yn!='y' && yn!='n'){
           printf("Please put in y or n!\n");
           yn=getchar();
        }
    }while(yn=='y' || yn=='Y');     //Not need to check 'n'
```

Comment: As already pointed out in the comments section of the question, it is a bad habit to store the return value of `getchar` in a variable of type `char`, because it can't store the return value `EOF`.